# Where this read/write operations limit being set on CloudSQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, postgresql-13

Is this value configurable by us, or this is limit by GCP?

[image: chart limit]

Other question is that write apparently are more than the limit after paralelizing from 1 to 10 threads more (only increase throughput by 2x, last few minutes from the chart above), what could be the possible cause of this?

Comment: Please indicate the specific database service (MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQL Server) for your Cloud SQL. Please provide your configuration for parallelizing threads from 1 to 10 so that we could get a clearer picture.

Comment: Google Cloud persistent disks have performance limits that are directly related to disk size. That might be a factor, but your post has few details on what you configured. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#performance_limits Based on your graph you are exceeding those limits.

Comment: @RobertG it is postgres 13, threads on the client side golang, just adding thread pool (the connection already connection pooled) `pool = pond.New(10, 5000); for ... { pool.Submit( ... ) } ; pool.StopAndWait()` using github.com/alitto/pond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to test whether read/write speed is configurable and I arrived with a conclusion that it is. You can change the read/write speed by changing the storage capacity.

Please check the images below:

This is a screenshot before changing the storage capacity:

[image]

And this is after changing the capacity:

[image]

I also noticed that if you're using HDD, write speed is higher than read speed:

[image]

You can only change storage capacity if an instance is already deployed. You can only select storage type when creating a new instance.

With regards write speed is over the limit, we can't make specific claims when changing thread value. There are several factors that this may cause:

- Workload performance could impact read/write speed depending on the characteristics of the workload. Workloads which are heavily multi-threaded or take advantage of high levels of parallelism may experience performance improvements when hyper-threading is enabled. Single-threaded or those with limited parallelism may see little to no benefit.
- Enabling hyper-threading increases the number of logical CPU cores only visible to the OS, which could result in increased context-switching overhead and potential resource contention or conflict over a shared resources between components, i.e., CPU, storage, RAM. This may have a slight impact on the performance of certain workloads.

It is recommended to monitor the performance metrics and conduct thorough testing before performing changes to the thread count in a Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: Robert, your answer is a good start for an article.